# We're trying to make hard crack candy,the humidity in the house is 50%

Tags: candy

Is there any way we can make it without it becoming sticky?

Comment: You can try this, but it's not guaranteed to work. Set you oven for 250F and let the heat drive off the humidity, turn the oven off and let it cool (while closed) for a few minutes before you put your candy in there to cool. Put your candy in there, shut the door and let it cool until hard.

Comment: Perhaps the fridge or freezer would have dryer air than the rest of the house?

Comment: The fridge will cause the candy to get wet. The freezer will cause the candy to crystallize and likely Ruin it.

Comment: Thanks we tried fridge and freezer it did get wetter in the,the oven is worth a try I might leave it open to dry the air in the kitchen thanks for the idea

Answer (score 1):

50% RH does not sound so bad actually.

In a hot-humid climate, chilling the food will only exacerbate the problem of condensation.

There are a few options. Put them into an air tight container with some food grade silica gel desiccant. Alternatively, a bowl of salt (you can pre-heat the salt slightly) will do a similar job.

Use a food dehydrator, but you will still have a wetting/sticky problem during storage.